# I can't connect to the database via Windows authentication (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I need Windows authentication. I don't need SQL Server authentication.

I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "EfCoreBasicDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'LIZARD\BLAKD'.'

My code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string\[\] args)
    {
        using var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SELECT 1");
    
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Name Provider: {dbContext.Database.ProviderName}.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(
                @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EfCoreBasicDb;Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; Integrated Security=True")

            .EnableDetailedErrors()
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .LogTo(
                Console.WriteLine,
                new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name },
                LogLevel.Information);
    }
}
```

Login is correct in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

[User Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruGro.png)

[Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRiuj.png)

I looked through all the answers on this topic, checked the login parameters presented in the pictures, and also used different options in the connection string. It doesn't work for me:

```
Trusted_Connection=True; Integrated Security=SSPI; Integrated Security=true; TrustServerCertificate=True
```

Comment: Were you able to login via Server Management Studio with the windows details?

Comment: I am able to login via Server Management Studio. 
I use only:
Server type: Database Engine
Server name: LIZARD\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: Windows authentication
User name: LIZARD\BLAKD

What Windows details did you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the cause of the error.
In Server Management Studio you had to manually enter.

Server name: (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Before this, it did not appear in the list of possible servers, so there was no way to make a database there that could be connected to.
There could also be a problem with the certificate.
Method 1:

Where is Login In Server Managment Studio . Options => Connection Properties => Trust server certificate

Method 2:

In the connection line write:

```
TrustServerCertificate=True
```